# Adjective for combining some lower dimensional objects to form a higher dimensional object

Tags: single-word-requests, mathematics, science, academia

Are there some English words that describe the dimension of objects changed, by combining some lower dimensional objects to form a higher dimensional object. For example, from the lower dimensional object (like a point in 0 dimension) to a higher dimensional object (like a line/string in 1 dimension)?

What I can come up with is the "**dimensional transmutation.**" However, are there shorten single word for this concept? Any adjective for this concept? This is required to be used in a scientific or math article.

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with the suggested answer of "transposition". Transposing rearranges the dimensions without affecting dimensionality.

In the abstract sense, I would say that a lower dimensional concept *generalizes* into higher dimensions (e.g. an n-sphere is the generalisation of a circle) but that doesn't necessarily work for the specific act of combining lower dimensional structures to form higher dimensional ones of a specific dimensionality. I would simply call this *extension*: two one-dimensional lines arranged perpendicularly is an extension into the two-dimensional plane. Three perpendicular lines extend to a three dimensional space, and so on.

In the specific case of geometry, we can also talk about *projection* into higher-dimensional spaces.

Comment: I would not suggest the word *projection* as it refers to a kind of mapping from a set onto a subset of itself. In other words, OP seems to be looking for an antonym for *projection*, which does not seem to exist. I have seen the verb "lift" used in some technical settings, e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/310826/37705

Answer (score 2):

I don’t believe there’s a general term for this, since it depends on the particular operation. One option is *extend*, for example, “a 3-dimensional Euclidean space can be formed by *extending* the *x*–*y* plane with an additional perpendicular *z* axis”, or “*extend* the line *L* by one unit in the positive *z* direction to form a plane”.

I would suggest you use the most specific term available for each instance. If you have some particular means of combining objects that you’re using, then refer to that specifically. You might take a curve and create a *surface of revolution* about a particular axis. You might take a point, line, plane, or cube and *extend* or *extrude* it into a line, plane, prism, or hypercube, respectively; or take two and *connect* or *fuse* them according to some rule. The most general term I can think of is simply *generalise*—for example, take a space-filling curve and *generalise* it to a higher dimension.

Comment: thanks, “a 3-dimensional Euclidean space can be formed by extending the x–y plane with an additional perpendicular z axis” this is the correct example.

Comment: This is the best answer, especially considering paragraph 2. There isn't a generally applicable answer, but paragraph 1 is likely what you want. Well done.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of what you are expressing is that '**transposition**' would be more suitable than 'transmutation'. If I understand correctly there is no fundamental mathematical change. It is a dimensional change but the (combined) entity is transposed into another dimension.

The meanings of 'transposition' given in [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/205037?redirectedFrom=transposition#eid) list two that appear, to me, to be relevant :

> 3b. Math. The interchange of each row of a matrix with the corresponding column.

and :

> 4. Algebra. Transference of a quantity from one side of an equation (or one member of a proportion) to the other.

Comment: But the dimension is different by 1. I dont know does it capture it

Comment: @wonderich I think you are better placed than I to comment on that aspect.